# ios7 - control the design of the camera app from my app

Tags: ios7

I am building an app that in some point refers to the camera app to take a picture, and then comes back to my app with the picture.

when I go into the camera app, can I redesign it?
for example- can I change the color of the buttons from white to red?

thanx.